# Is there a better alternative to solve std::condition_variable symbol linkage error with GLIBC

Tags: c++, gcc, glibc

There is a problem when using **std::condition_variable** and compiling with g++ on Linux which has glibc-2.30. But it does not run on RHEL 7 with glibc-2.17. The reason is **std::condition_variable::wait_for()** is linked to **pthread_cond_clockwait()** function, which is introduced in glibc-2.30. The gcc packge was built from source with glibc-2.30.

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/std_mutex.h :

```
...
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_PTHREAD_COND_CLOCKWAIT
    void
    wait_until(mutex& __m, clockid_t __clock, timespec& __abs_time)
    {
      pthread_cond_clockwait(&_M_cond, __m.native_handle(), __clock,
                 &__abs_time);
    }
#endif
...
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
 
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;
int i;
 
void waits(int idx)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    if(cv.wait_for(lk, idx*100ms, []{return i == 1;})) 
        std::cerr << "Thread " << idx << " finished waiting. i == " << i << '\n';
    else
        std::cerr << "Thread " << idx << " timed out. i == " << i << '\n';
}
 
void signals()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(120ms);
    std::cerr << "Notifying...\n";
    cv.notify_all();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        i = 1;
    }
    std::cerr << "Notifying again...\n";
    cv.notify_all();
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits, 1), t2(waits, 2), t3(waits, 3), t4(signals);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

The source code was copied to a file **test.cpp** and compiled with a small script **build.sh**.

*build.sh*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    
/opt/gcc-11.3.0/bin/g++ \
  -std=c++17 -O3 -pthread -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc glibc_test.cpp -o test_glibc
```

Then **test_glibc** is copied to RHEL 7 and **ldd test_glibc** has delivered this issue:

```
./test_glibc: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.30' not found (required by ./test_glibc)
```

The only solution I have found was to modify the **configure** file in **gcc/libstdc++-v3** folder and compile the gcc package again. **glibcxx_cv_PTHREAD_COND_CLOCKWAIT=yes** is modified to **glibcxx_cv_PTHREAD_COND_CLOCKWAIT=no**

```
if ac_fn_cxx_try_compile "$LINENO"; then :
  glibcxx_cv_PTHREAD_COND_CLOCKWAIT=no
else
  glibcxx_cv_PTHREAD_COND_CLOCKWAIT=no
fi
```

and

```
if ac_fn_cxx_try_link "$LINENO"; then :
  glibcxx_cv_PTHREAD_COND_CLOCKWAIT=no
else
  glibcxx_cv_PTHREAD_COND_CLOCKWAIT=no
fi
```

So my question, is there any other solution to solve the problem with incompatible newer glibc functions to older versions?

Comment: Can you not build everything with glibc-2.17?

Comment: Naive suggestion: might it be possible to provide your own implementation of `pthread_cond_clockwait`?

Comment: In modern C++ I want use std functionality and not invent the wheel again or do you mean implement pthread_cond_clockwait and map symbol with  **__asm__(".symver cust_pthread_cond_clockwait, cust_pthread_cond_clockwait@GLIBC_2.2.5");** ?

Comment: @Caleth I have tried to compile with glibc-2.17 but other problems occurred build gcc from scratch and configuration has stopped.

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question asking about those errors, because you are trying to link executables for two different environments. You are *lucky* that an error stopped you here, it sounds like you are in undefined behaviour land

Comment: @PaulSanders that's what I was going to propose. Provide your own implementation of `pthread_cond_clockwait`. Have it call system's `pthread_cond_clockwait` if present (use dlsym with RTLD_NEXT), otherwise call `pthread_cond_timedwait` and ignore the clock parameter.

Comment: It is a general problem, if an application is compiled with a newer glibc version and this one should run on Linux with an older glibc version where a function is introduced in the newer glibc version which is not exist in older version. There are some circumstances to support older Linux versions due customers have such systems. But in the development we want going further with the usage of C++ standard. These causes some conflicts.

Comment: This problem of binary incompatibility is real but it has little to do with the C++ standard. The usual solution is to admit non-portability of binaries and build for a specific OS using tools and libraries of that OS. If your customer has Linux with an older libc, you build for them against that older libc, with tools configured to use that libc. Usually on a dedicated build machine.

Comment: Non-portable software solutions are costly and time-consuming. I think companies would not be happy with these circumstances. Then we can forget about Linux as a portable friendly operating system. If the solution is to create a separate binary for each different Linux version.

Comment: There is portability forwards in time, but not backwards in time. Nobody promised you portability backwards in time. It is, for all intents and purposes, impossible. See, new versions of glibc try very hard not to break old features, but they do add new features, and compilers use these new features when available. It's called progress. If you don't like it, pick a version of glibc frozen at some point back in time, and use it for all your development.

Comment: The sufficient solution is to build the tool chain on an older Linux distribution which has the minimum required **glibc** version and use this as a build system.